# Tengo problemas para instalar ubuntu / I have problems installing ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

Mi PC
en asrock a320m hdv r3.0 AMD A10-9700 RADEON R7, 10 COMPUTE CORES 4C+6G    3.50 GHz

Tengo problemas con la instalacion de Ubuntu 23.04.
Probé usar Ventoy, Balena y Rufus para crear un USB BOOT.
Pero todos tienen el mismo problema. Inicia GRUB. Selecciono para instalar. Aparece el logo de ubuntu y se reinicia.
Bootsecurity esta desactivado.
Que puedo hacer?

My PC
asrock a320m hdv r3.0 AMD A10-9700 RADEON R7, 10 COMPUTE CORES 4C+6G 3.50 GHz

I have problems installing Ubuntu 23.04.
I tried using Ventoy, Balena and Rufus to create a USB BOOT.
But all have the same problem. Start GRUB. I select to install. The ubuntu logo appears and reboots.
Bootsecurity is disabled.
What I can do?

Comment: You've provided no Ubuntu product & release details, nor architecture. Are you hoping we'll guess? Is your chosen Ubuntu product suitable for your device? On some releases different ISOs are available that use different installers too, but you gave no specifics as to Ubuntu.

Comment: download the version ubuntu 23.04

Comment: This is a Q&A site, so please add additional details to your question; it's also an English only site, so remove the non-english please. 23.04 is also only partial detail; as you've not said if Desktop, Server, or *flavor* or provide architecture details (*does it match your hardware*), and if Desktop which ISO (*installer*) you tried; as there are ISOs for download of Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop using `ubuntu-desktop-installer` OR `ubiquity`, or `subiquity` for Ubuntu 23.04 Server, and two *flavors* using `calamares` for Ubuntu 23.04 too (*other flavors use `ubiquity`*).  Please be specific.